CMAK Yikes! Ask timed out on [ActorSelection[Anchor(akka://kafka-manager-system/)
i am trying to implement apache kafka on docker based on this article https://medium.com/simform-engineering/set-up-kafka-ecosystem-on-local-machine-1a00a436c0ba.
I have altered the yml compose file so the port the have described i correctly bounded
.YML COMPOSE FILE
version: '3'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOO_MY_ID: 1
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 192.168.0.1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
  kafka_manager:
    image: kafkamanager/kafka-manager
    container_name: kafka-manager
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    environment:
      ZK_HOSTS: "zookeeper:2181"
      APPLICATION_SECRET: "random-secret"

When i started the containers i can't create an cluster because i get this error:  KeeperErrorCode = Unimplemented for /kafka-manager/mutex. I managed to fix this error with this article KeeperErrorCode = Unimplemented for /kafka-manager/mutex
Now i see the cluster in my cluster

But when i press on MyFirstCluster(see picture above). I get the following error
Yikes! Ask timed out on [ActorSelection[Anchor(akka://kafka-manager-system/), Path(/user/kafka-manager/MyFirstCluster/kafka-state)]] after [2000 ms]. Message of type [kafka.manager.model.ActorModel$KSGetBrokers$] was sent by [Actor[akka://kafka-manager-system/user/kafka-manager/MyFirstCluster#-549568985]]. A typical reason for `AskTimeoutException` is that the recipient actor didn't send a reply.

This is what i have tried:

Enable Active OffsetCache ( https://github.com/yahoo/CMAK/issues/148 )

Can you please help me with this error.

This issue is likely occurring because you're using localhost:2181 for your Zookeeper hosts. When containers are trying to communicate within a Docker cluster, you should use the service name instead of localhost. This allows the containers to resolve the correct network address within the cluster.

